# Vertical center of menu in a header

Tags: css, center

I am not able to center my menu in a header-bar.

I've tried `display: table-cell` and `display: table` but it doesn't work. The only thing I can do is a fixed margin-top, which I want to avoid.

```
  <header>
          <div class="container">
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <div id="mainnav">
                  <div class="clearfix">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'depth' => 1)); ?>
                  </di>
                </div>
          </div>
  </header>


    div#mainnav {
        height: 120px;
        width: 70%;
        float: right;
        background-color: red;
        display:table; 
    }

    div.menu {
     background-color: yellow;
     display:table-cell;  
     vertical-align:middle;  
     text-align:center; }

    /* clearfix */
    div.menu ul:after {
       content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
       visibility: hidden;
       display: block;
       height: 0;
       clear: both;
    }
```

I used cleafix to have a div.menu height (it was 0 before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centered (table-cell) div needs to be **directly** under the container (table) div.

You seem to have no .menu in the code, or maybe the PHP generates it - either way, it's nested inside. You might want to make the `#mainnav` itself as the clearfix, so that the children below it will be directly there.

```
<div id="mainnav" class="clearfix">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'depth' => 1)); ?>
</div>
```

Here's an example:

```css
#mainnav {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px;
}

#mainnav .menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainnav">
  <div class="menu-item">My menu item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code like this instead of display property. Is there any reason to use "display:table"?

### UPDATED CSS

```
div.menu {
background-color: yellow;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
height: 120px;}
```

Comment: I wanted to make it more flexible, not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css

```
div.menu {
  background-color: yellow;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  }
```

and

```
ul, ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

ul use default margin & padding if not set.